# How do I resolve writing image with distortions?

Tags: image, rust

I have only one problem, which is that the write_photo() method always write distorted image as output.

The image created is always filled with rainbows and grey shades

Cargo.toml

```ini
[dependencies]
image = "0.25.0"
```

main.rs

```rust
use image::{open, GenericImageView, ImageResult, RgbaImage};

fn main() {
    let path = "src/assets/test.jpeg";

    let output = "src/assets/check.jpeg";

    let (w, h, p) = read_photo(path).expect("Error");

    let _ = write_photo(output, w, h, &p).unwrap();
}

/// Reads a photo from a file and returns its dimensions and RGBA pixels

fn read_photo(file_path: &str) -> ImageResult<(u32, u32, Vec<u8>)> {
    let img = open(file_path)?;

    let (width, height) = img.dimensions();

    let pixels = img.to_rgba8().into_raw();

    println!("read image");

    Ok((width, height, pixels))
}

/// Writes a photo to a file with the given dimensions and RGBA pixels

fn write_photo(
    file_path: &str,
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
    pixels: &[u8],
) -> Result<(), image::ImageError> {
    let img = RgbaImage::from_raw(width, height, pixels.to_vec()).ok_or(
        image::ImageError::Parameter(image::error::ParameterError::from_kind(
            image::error::ParameterErrorKind::DimensionMismatch,
        )),
    );

    img?.save(file_path)?;

    println!("write image");

    Ok(())
}
```

That's all I have in my main.rs

Comment: I am able to confirm but haven't found where exactly the issue is. Changing it to save as `.png` seems to work though so it may be a bug.

Comment: Ok, downgrading to `image v0.24.9` seems to work correctly with this code unchanged. So I believe it is a bug in the 0.25 version.

Comment: I concur with @kmdreko. I want to add, that downgrading to `0.24.9` "worked" for a few large images I tested, but still produced garbage for smaller images. So far I also haven't found a [submitted issue](https://github.com/image-rs/image/issues), that directly refers to this issue

Comment: Another insight: changing this code to use `RgbImage` and `.to_rgb8` (i.e. no alpha channel) seemed to work as well. (only testing one image though).

Comment: The data returned by `.to_rgba8()` is correct. So the issue must be in the encoder

Comment: I have tried using "PNG" on the output it works fine

Comment: I also did downgrade the version as suggested by @kmdreko

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug with `image` version `0.25.0` when saving to JPEG from RGBA pixels. I have filed an issue here: https://github.com/image-rs/image/issues/2173

Workarounds:

- downgrading to `0.24.9`, or
- using no alpha channel (i.e. `RgbImage` and `.to_rgb8()`), or
- saving as `.png` (or potentially any another format)